# How to use SELECT in NHibernate mapping?

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

Right now I have a second code in my mapping:

```
  <class name="Order" table="tOrder">
    <id name="Id">
      <column name="Ref" sql-type="int"/>
      <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <property name="OrderNo" column="OrderNo"/>
    <property name="CustomerId" column="CustomerId"/>
    <join table="tOffer">
      <key column="Ref" unique="true"/>
      <component name="User" class="User" >
        <property name="Id" column="OfferId"/>
        <property name="UserName" column="UserName"/>
      </component>
      <component name="Driver" class="Contact">
        <property name="FirstName" column="FirstName"/>
        <property name="LastName" column="LastName"/>
        <property name="Email" column="DriverEMail"/>
        <property name="Fax" column="DriverFax"/>
        <property name="Phone" column="DriverTelephone"/>
      </component>
    </join>
```

Seems fine (and it is, its working without problem), there are issue.

Some fields for Driver class are incorrect (FirstName, LastName).
They should take data for those field from different database. In theory it should look something like this:

```
<join table="tDriver">
      <key column="Ref" unique="true"/>
      <component name="Driver" class="Contact">
        <property name="FirstName" column="Firstname"/>
        <property name="LastName" column="Lastname"/>
      </component>
</join>
```

But I can't do that because Driver was already declared in mapping. This issue can be easily fixed with View help, but there is another Issue, I shouldn't make any changes in database (can't create View).
As I understand, there are possibility to use:

```
<sql-query name="...">...</sql-query>
```

And inside it should be selected data for Driver from tOffer and additional two fields from tDriver.
So, my question is, how should it look correctly and will it work at all? I mean, will there we any issues with another mapping properties?

**EDIT:**

Inside  should be something like that I guess, but how to use it...

```
  Select d.Firstname, d.Lastname, o.DriverEMail, o.DriverFax , o.DriverTelephone
  FROM tOffer as o WITH (nolock)
  INNER JOIN tDriver as d WITH (nolock) on d.Ref = o.Ref
```

P.S Sorry about my English.

Comment: You could use the nhibernate linq provider or the queryover provider and issue the query that represents the data you want to bring back.  You could abstract this however you want to be able to reuse it across any of your applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NHibernate supports the view-like mapping. Instead of using attribute `table="tableName"` *(targeting the table or view)* we can use another approach **`<subselect>`**

The mapping then could look like this:

```
<join table=""> <!-- table="" attribute should be there, even empty-->
  <subselect>
      Select d.Firstname    AS FirstName
       , d.Lastname         AS LastName
       , o.DriverEMail      AS Email
       , o.DriverFax        AS Fax
       , o.DriverTelephone  AS Phone
       , d.Ref              AS Ref
      FROM tOffer as o WITH (nolock)
      INNER JOIN tDriver as d WITH (nolock) on d.Ref = o.Ref
  </subselect>
  <key column="Ref" unique="true"/>
  <component name="Driver" class="Contact">
    <!-- NOTE if the name and column do fit... the column def is redundant.. -->
    <property name="FirstName" column="FirstName"/>
    <property name="LastName"  column="LastName"/>
    <property name="Email"     column="Email"/>
    <property name="Fax"       column="Fax"/>
    <property name="Phone"     column="Phone"/>
  </component>
  ...
</join>
```

Do **NOT** forget to also return the column **`REF`** which will be the way how to JOIN both entities

Comment: Hm...So... Key and colums will be taken from this sub select... like column="prop1" and column="prop2"...  do I understand it correct enough?

Comment: Absolutely... please, try it. `<subselect>` definition is not so well documented, but in fact could replace any "table" attribute and serve as a *"run time view"*. But of course, it is mostly suitable for readonly handling... good luck

Comment: Hm... didn't work out. Component - I tried to use <component name="Driver" class="Contact"> but I got an exception: Invalid column name 'Driver'. I edit my question to show what didn't work out.

Comment: Oh - got it, I dint have Driver... I'm a morror

Comment: This concept is working, I tried locally, just be sure that you are using the proper aliasing... I tried to update my answer, also, please, do not forget to use **Ref** column ... to be joined with our root entity...

Comment: Don't worry, I found that I forgot to change column name for some fields... my bad. Will try again now.

Comment: Great to see that Olegs, NHibernate is a great tool, Enjoy it ;)